# Print job status of windows (samba) print queue from CUPS

Tags: linux, printing, samba, smb, cups

We have a Windows machine with a shared printer (printer1) available as smb://winpc/printer1

When sending a job from CUPS to smb://winpc/printer1, the job leaves the CUPS queue and is marked as successfully printed, even when it has not yet been printed (The job still exists in the Windows print queue).

Is there a way to query the job status of print queue on Windows from CUPS?
Alternatively, can a successfully_printed event be fired from CUPS when the job leaves the Windows print queue?

Comment: EnumJobs (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160129): This basically provides what i am looking for, except not sure how to call this over the network from a Linux machine?

Comment: Hi adzail, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is additional info on question. I used to work for Adzail and created nodeJS script witch utilize the problem. https://gist.github.com/vodolaz095/5325917 But it cannot track status of windows shared printer. Anyway, i hope this help